# Naive Bayesian classifier calculation problem

Tags: bayesian, naive-bayes

I am having trouble calculating the Bayesian probability for this table, when doing naive Bayesian classifiers. When I try to calculate number 5 I get $1.25$ by doing the following:
$P(a=1|id=1)= \frac {3}{4},$ $P(b=2|id=1)= \frac {3}{4}$, $P(id=1)= \frac {1}{2},$
$P(a=1)= \frac {1}{2},$ $P(b=2)= \frac {1}{2}$ which leads to $P(id=1|a=1,b=2)= \frac {\frac {3}{4} \times \frac {3}{4} \times \frac {1}{2}}{\frac {1}{2} \times \frac {1}{2}} = 1.25$ Obviously this is wrong as a probability can't be more than $1$ but I am not sure where I went wrong.

[image: Table]

Comment: You are making *two* independence assumptions. 

(1) $P(a=1, b=2) \stackrel{?}{=} P(a=1) P(b=2)$ 

(2) $P(a=1, b=2 | id=1) \stackrel{?}{=} P(a=1|id=1) P(b=2|id=1)$. 

Your data shows that one of these assumptions is incorrect.

Comment: @RDK I was following this guide on Naive Bayesian classifiers [Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059594/a-simple-explanation-of-naive-bayes-classification/20556654#20556654) I followed the steps, and there appears to be lack of independence in the same way but those calculations work whereas mine won't.

Comment: If you insist on using the independence assumption, then I'd suggest you stick to either conditional independence assumption or unconditional independence. This choice affects the way you calculate the denominator. So lets define event $E = (a = 1, b = 2)$. So instead of calculating your denominator as $P(E)$ directly using table frequencies, you need to calculate it using total probability rule. $P(E) = \sum_k P(E|id = k)$. In your case it yields $P(E) = \frac{3}{4}\frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{2}$. You're going to get an answer which is inconsistent with the table.